# SLURM: Sinfo GresUsed

Tags: gpu, cluster-computing, slurm

How do you interpret the output format of GresUsed when running a command like "sinfo ... --Format=GresUsed"

The output of my node looks something like this:

gpu:h100:0(IDX:N/A)

What do all of this mean "0(IDX:N/A)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that none of the configured GRES of type GPU h100 are currently assigned to a job for that node:

```
gpu:h100:0(IDX:N/A)
^   ^    ^ ^
|   |    | | 
|   |    | + Indices of the allocated GPUs (here None Available (N/A) )
|   |    + Number of allocated GPUs (here 0)
|   + GPU type (here Nvidia Tesla H100)      
+ GRES type (here gpu)
```

On a node with multiple GPUs of which 4 are used, it would look like this:

```
gpu:h100:4(IDX:0-3)
```